# CSS selector for a label wrapped around a particular control?

Tags: css

I have this label and checkbox

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="SameAsPrimaryAddress" />Same As Primary Address</label>
```

Is there a CSS selector that will only affect the label text and not the checkbox or do I have to separate my label from the input or give the label an ID or class to be able to do this?

Comment: Can you wrap the text in a `<span>`? `label span { ... } `

Comment: why doesn't selecting the label affect the text(?)...it should HTML & CSS please in a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

## It depends

In that case and if you only need that HTML, you can.

## But

It is better to wrap your text with a `span` or a `div` to avoid problems you can encounter.

Here's a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/6aS4k/

Then you can add style with `label span {}`

Comment: you cannot because for example if you add a CSS property like `color`, the text in the input will be using the color.

Comment: it works in that specific case because he has only a input[checkbox] , add some div in it http://jsfiddle.net/6aS4k/

Comment: Th input is a **checkbox** so it doesn't have a color. I agree they should be separate elements and not wrapped but it **is** possible to style the text **in this instance**.

Answer (score 1):

**Your answer: No.** There *is no selector* to only target the free floating text of an element, without affecting the inherited properties of other elements within. To explicitly style your text, you would actually want to wrap your text in another element to target in your CSS, like a `span`.

**However,** in your specific case, that checkbox does not have many (if any) inherited properties in most browsers default stylesheet. So, a long as you aren't using a reset stylesheet or otherwise normalizing that input to inherit style properties you could get away with styling the `label` to affect only the text.

**In the end,** I would recommend that your label should actually correspond to your input separately, which would also semantically make sense. This would also allow you to make use of the `for` attribute, which will allow  clicking on your label to toggle the corresponding checkbox as well, which is a win for usability!

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="SameAsPrimaryAddress" />
  <label for="SameAsPrimaryAddress">Same As Primary Address</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree that they should be separate but it's possible to style the text even if they are not. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/K93gU/

Comment: @Paulie_D that's not entirely correct. You've just chosen a property to which you cannot see the checkbox's inheritance. Any property that the checkbox inherits will be there, including this color in your example. You have, in fact, colored the text of the checkbox red, just, in this case, the checkbox does not contain text. I can add an edit comment to clarify.

Comment: @rgthree That doesn't appear to be the case. Here's my example above except with type='text' and the color only affects the label: http://jsfiddle.net/coreyog/eQBY3/ Both IE and Chrome behave this way (black text in textbox, red text in label)

Comment: @CoreyOgburn You're right. The default browser stylesheets define color, so it is not an inherited property. A lot of "reset" stylesheets may make that inherited, in which case it would have been. I've update my answer to reflect the possibilities.

Comment: Your point about clicking the label is not entirely correct, in that the OP's markup *already has* the usability of clicking on the label to select the input. Wrapping an input element inside a label element is semantic HTML and has the same effect as using matched "for" and "id" attributes.